# Error in a "Street View containers"

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

I was make Street view containers. I was see [that link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-embed).

But i cannot see Street view in my browser /Google chrome/

Please teach me my mistake and my error.
Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>アスタンソーチのGoogle-APIです。</title>
<link href="/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>


<script>

function initialize() {
    var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(32.785473,129.862451);
    var panoramaOptions = {
        position: fenway,
        pov: {
            heading: 165,
            pitch: 0
        },
    zoom: 1
    };

    var myPano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
        document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        panoramaOptions);
    myPano.setVisible(true);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: #map-canvas needs a height when you want to see anything

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

The problem is in the following line at the top

`<link href="/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">`

when your website is hosted on your own server location, your map page cannot find the css file.

you need to add the following css to your file;

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map-canvas, #map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
}

@media print {
  html, body {
    height: auto;
  }

  #map-canvas, #map_canvas {
    height: 650px;
  }
}

#panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -180px;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

or you need to add it to a new file called default.css located at yourwebsitesAddress.com//\maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css